# Escape iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I know how to escape the iframe. I have a link:

```
<a id="aaa" href="http://localhost/projectManagement/users" target="_parent" >Sign up</a>
```

### by clicking on that link I will escape the iframe

the problem is that I want to escape the iframe when clicking on a button not a link.

I know how to execute JavaScript with the click of a button so I have been working on executing that link with javascriopt

things I have tried out:

html:  (it is inside a iframe)

```
<button onClick="tempEvent();" style="width: 500px; height: 50px; margin-top: -15px; font-size: 20px;">
      <b>
          click me              
       </b>
</button>
<div style="height: 15px;">
</div>
<a id="aaa" href="http://localhost/projectManagement/users" target="_parent" >Sign up</a>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
    function tempEvent()
    {

        clickLink(document.getElementById('aaa'));  // this technique does not work on firefox!
        fireEvent(document.getElementById("aaa"),'click'); // this technique does not work in firefox eather.

        document.getElementById("aaa").onclick(); 
    }

    function clickLink(link) {
        if (document.createEvent) {
            var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                false, false, false, false,
                0, null);
            link.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        else if (link.fireEvent) {
           link.fireEvent("onclick");
        }
    }

    function fireEvent(obj,evt){    
        var fireOnThis = obj;
        if( document.createEvent ) {
          var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
          evObj.initEvent( evt, true, false );
          fireOnThis.dispatchEvent(evObj);
        } else if( document.createEventObject ) {
          fireOnThis.fireEvent('on'+evt);
        }
    }



</script>
```

I know I can replace the button with the link but I am just dont understand why I cannot achieve this!

### edit

Even if I place the link inside the button it does not work!

Comment: Is the javascript you gave inside the iframe or within the parent?

Comment: when clicking on the button I get redirected escaping the iframe with the chrome browser. but Firefox does not do it

Comment: Escape the iframe. It's almost lyrical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript in **parent**:

```
function redirectMe(url) {
    window.location = url;
}
```

Javascript in **child iframe**:

```
function tempEvent() {
    parent.redirectMe('http://localhost/projectManagement/users');
}
```

You can bypass the `<a>` all together, and the whole clickLink/fireEvent is not really needed.  If you did need to activate the click event on a link, check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and its [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="button" onclick="try { window.parent.location.href = "http://example.com"; } catch(e) { }" />
```

Or, if you don't know the url, or simply which to store the url on the element:

```
<input type="button" href="http://example.com" onclick="try { window.parent.location.href = this.href; } catch(e) { }" />
```

Remember, the onclick event doesn't always have to refer to a function. It is capable of running JavaScript codes right from the handler, although most prefer functions.

**Note:** I added the `try { } catch(e) { }` statement due to possible cross-domain issues in which trying to manipulate the parent window would result in an error being thrown.

Comment: That may work in most browsers, but I don't think all browsers support modifying the parent `window` global from a child iframe.

Comment: As far as I know, all browsers run JavaScript from event handlers the same way they do normal script. (Unless of course it is an event like onunload.) The only reason it would disallow you to do this is because the domain of the iframe isn't the same as it's parent. This is the exact reason I added the `try { } catch(e) { }` statement.